# Catalog Price Rule (with SKU) not working

Tags: magento2

Trying to make a catalog price rule for SKU's, but it doesn't work.

Try it with the whole categorie and than it works fine.

Someone can help me out?

edit:
see image for config[image]

Comment: The error maybe in some other part of process, please mention the price rule config of admin

Comment: Please share  your rules setting

Comment: see post for image or: https://www.mupload.nl/db/amb7tju12v

Comment: Have you installed any module or written any code that overrides the default magento functionality related to cart rules?

Comment: @SourabhKumarSharma, no i don't have 3rd party modules installed related to cart rules.

Comment: Another reason for this to not work can be that you have saved this rule in another webiste and testing it on another website, scope maybe the issue.

Comment: @SourabhKumarSharma And i think i only have one store view... I try it again and did't saw any other storeview upcoming

Comment: Can you try adding a simple same like demo1 in both rule name and coupon code field and test it.

Comment: @SourabhKumarSharma, oke, gonna test it! Let you know.

Comment: @SourabhKumarSharma, nope, not working. Can you check my admin?

Comment: Still experiencing this in Magento 2.2.6.  The catalog rule only takes the first sku.  It won't apply to all the skus.

Comment: @Joost have you got any solution for this? i am facing this issue.

Comment: @ChiragPatel, no still does'nt have a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue.

Try the next workaround: Set only one SKU number in each SKU field.

[image]

Comment: This problem is already solved in new versions: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/ec45e6357180bd936071f66953632fc0e4a45732

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps:

- On the Admin panel, click Stores. In the Attributes section, select
  Product
- Search SKU attribute and click to open
- Go to Storefront Properties & then select Use for Promo Rule
  Conditions => Yes & save

> php bin/magento cache:flush

Hope this helps you !!!

Comment: doesn't work on my side. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The first is you should be use the action **is_one_of**.

Then, when you selected different sku from admin, Magento add a space between the skus. Ej:

```
1001348, 1001349, 1001350
```

This is a bug of Magento, you should remove the spaces between them. The final list should be

```
1001348,1001349,1001350
```